# SignalR - how to invoke client method from a class in a different assembly?

Tags: signalr

Can anyone out there help me to understand

how to invoke the client method from server method using SignalR The server class resides in an CustomEvent handler in a different assembly.

I tried 3 different methods to invoke the method:

I named my hub as [HubName("notificationhub")]

Method1

```
Clients.addMessage(message);
```

This gives "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference"

Method 2

```
IHubContext context1 = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext("notificationhub");
context1.Clients.addMessage('hello');
```

The client remained silent.

Method3

```
var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:21120/");
var notification= hubConnection.CreateProxy("notificationhub");
hubConnection.Start().Wait();
notification.Invoke("Send", "Hello").Wait();
```

This method gives error : {"The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."} To my surprise, i am able to invoke this method from a console application using the 3rd method.

what is the best solution for implementing this and what is the reason why i am not able to invoke the client method? Can anyone help me with this?

Regards
Vince

Comment: You need to give more detail as I don't really understand your project structure based on your description.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how Im doing it, a bit a hack, but it works.  It only works when calling hub from a controller, otherwise it wont work.  Use UpdateHubFromController method.

```
public class UpdateFeedActivity : Hub
{
    readonly IHubContext _hubContext ;

    public UpdateFeedActivity()
    {
        _hubContext = _hubContext ?? GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<UpdateFeedActivity>();
    }

    public void UpdateFeed(string groupname, string itemId, Enums.FeedActivityTypes activityType,
                                                                               string userId="",
                                                                               string actionResult1="", 
                                                                               string actionResult2="", 
                                                                               string actionResult3="")
    {
       Clients.Group(groupname).updateMessages(new FeedHubResponse
                                              {
                                                  ItemId = itemId,
                                                  ActivityType = activityType.ToString(),
                                                  UserId = userId,
                                                  ActionResult1 = actionResult1,
                                                  ActionResult2 = actionResult2,
                                                  ActionResult3 = actionResult3
                                              });
    }

    public void UpdateFeedFromController(string groupname, string itemId, Enums.FeedActivityTypes activityType,
                                                                               string userId = "",
                                                                               string actionResult1 = "",
                                                                               string actionResult2 = "",
                                                                               string actionResult3 = "")
    {
        _hubContext.Clients.Group(groupname).updateMessages(new FeedHubResponse
        {
            ItemId = itemId,
            ActivityType = activityType.ToString(),
            UserId = userId,
            ActionResult1 = actionResult1,
            ActionResult2 = actionResult2,
            ActionResult3 = actionResult3
        });
    }



    public void Join(string groupname)
    {
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupname);  
    }
}

public class FeedHubResponse
{
    public string ItemId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string ActionResult1 { get; set; }
    public string ActionResult2 { get; set; }
    public string ActionResult3 { get; set; }
    public string ActivityType { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```